# get post by post name instead of id

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok i have this code currently.

```
<?php

$post_id = 266;
echo "<div id='widgets-wrapper3'><div id='marginwidgets' style='overflow: auto; max-    width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; border: none !important;'>";
$queried_post = get_post($post_id); 
echo "<div class='thewidgets'>";
echo substr($queried_post->post_content, 0, 500);
echo "<a href='".get_permalink( 26 )."' title='Read the whole post' class='rm'>Read     More</a>";
echo "</div>";

echo "</div></div>";

?>
```

As you can see to the above code, the routine is to get the post by ID, but my permalinks change into post name instead of post id for SEO purposes. How do I get the post by post name?

Hope someone here could figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: post the `get_post()` method you might want to change that method.

Comment: @Deepak: what do you mean? i dont get it.

Comment: @Deepak http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `WP_Query`. This function will retrieve the first post with the given name, or `null` if nothing is found:

```php
function get_post_by_name(string $name, string $post_type = "post") {
    $query = new WP_Query([
        "post_type" => $post_type,
        "name" => $name
    ]);

    return $query->have_posts() ? reset($query->posts) : null;
}
```

By default this will search for an item of the type `post`:

`get_post_by_name("my-post")`

As a second argument you can set that to something else:

`get_post_by_name("my-page", "page")`

Answer (score 27):

### get_page_by_path()

WordPress has a built-in function that might help, with a few words of caution.

`<?php get_page_by_path( $page_path, $output, $post_type ) ?>`

[Here's the relevant Codex entry](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/).

To get a post, rather than a page, you just need to supply 'post' as the `$post_type` argument, and usually `OBJECT` (with no quotes) as the `$output` type, like this:

`<?php get_page_by_path( 'my_post_slug', OBJECT, 'post' ) ?>`

**Note** this function does not check the published or private status of the matched post. This is great if the item you're looking for is and attachment, but can be problematic for posts and pages (ie drafts, private posts etc.)

**Note** if it *is* a page you're looking for, and that page is hierarchical (ie: it has a parent), then you need to supply the entire path, that is: 'parent_page_slug/my_page_slug'.

### WP_Query / get_posts()

If either of these are a problem for you, then you should consider just using the `WP_Query` class to get your post by `name`:

```
$found_post = null;

if ( $posts = get_posts( array( 
    'name' => 'my_post_slug', 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
) ) ) $found_post = $posts[0];

// Now, we can do something with $found_post
if ( ! is_null( $found_post ) ){
    // do something with the post...
}
```

Comment: @Torben your comment is incorrect. `name` is the correct parameter to use.

Answer (score 10):

```
function get_post_by_name($post_name, $output = OBJECT) {
    global $wpdb;
        $post = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type='post'", $post_name ));
        if ( $post )
            return get_post($post, $output);

    return null;
}
```

Something this.